# Update Few Product Info Data using Custom API in Opencart 3

Tags: php, json, api, opencart, opencart-3

I am attempting to update a product's **Stock/Quantity, SKU, Colour, Size** value from another website using API.

I need to Product Info page as a front side. open page after updating data using API.

**JSON API DATA Format :**

```
{
"stock": 1503,
"sku": "00011919515264",
"color": "Navy",
"size": "Small"
},
```

Using this API I am able to retrieve my products in JSON Dictionary Format.

I now want to update a product's value as well.

Any idea How can I do easy ways?

Comment: take a look at [this post](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=182264#p667468), you can also use the ModelCatalogProduct model to retrieve and update each product